# file opening in C++

Tags: c++, variables, fstream

I am relatively new to C++ and I wanted to practice file opening and putting text in, now I realize this would be the worst way to store login info, but it is just how I chose to simulate it as at least it wont be totally random.  Now I am doing very well in all but one place it seems as I keep getting errors the whole code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <new>
using namespace std;
string login() {
    string username, password;
    cout << "What is your username?\n";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "What is your password, " << username << endl;
    cin >> password;
    //Verify info
    return username;
}
string signup() {
    string username, password, cpass, bio;
    do {
        cout << "What is your username?\n";
        cin >> username;
        cout << "What is your password?\n";
        cin >> password;
        cout << "Confirm password: ";
        cin >> cpass;
        cout << "Describe what you like to do:\n";
        cin >> bio;
    } while (password != cpass);
    ofstream user = new ofstream();
    user("users.txt");
    if (user.is_open()) {
        //Make sure the program is writing to the end of the file!
        user.seekp(0,std::ios::end);
        user << username << endl;
        user << password << endl;
        user << bio << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Something went wrong with opening the file!";
    }
    user.close();
    return username;
}
int main() {
    string answ;
    cout << "Hello, welcome to wewillscamyou.net, are you already signed up?\n";
    if(answ == "Yes" || answ == "yes") {
        string username = login();
    } else {
        string username = signup();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but I am getting errors at these two lines, it is not because of a typo, and I need help because this would work in java:

```
ofstream user = new ofstream();
user("users.txt");
```

Comment: `std::ofstream user("users.txt");`

Comment: Let me guess, you know Java and you're trying to learn C++?

Comment: ofstream user = new ofstream(); 
user is not pointer

Comment: yes @SamVarshavchik

Comment: In this case, the best thing you can do for yourself is completely forget everything you know about Java. C++ is not Java. Despite the deceptively similar syntax, classes and objects in C++ work in fundamentally different ways; and if you keep trying to draw analogies to Java, when trying to learn C++, you will always only confuse yourself, like here.

Comment: One rule of thumb that Java developers should take to heart if learning C++:  don't use the `new` keyword.    Because, as a Java developer, if you are using `new`, you are probably using a Java approach which doesn't work the same way in C++.     Get into the habit of avoiding `new`, and you'll learn faster.    [There are circumstances where using `new` is appropriate in C++ but, until you learn to think in C++ terms rather than in Java terms, you probably won't encounter them].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buddy in C++ `new` is used to create *dynamically allocated* object, or object that you have pointer to, or that you have to allocate memory for. Usually that is pointer to an object.

```
class A {
    public:
        A() { }
};

int main () {
    A a (); // object (created as value)
    A *a = new A(); // notice pointer, I need to allocate memory for it thus I have to use `new`
}
```

In conclusion `new` in C++ means allocate enough memory for this object and give me the address of it. So to solve your error you have several choices:

```
ofstream user ("user.txt");
```

or

```
ofstream user;
user = ofstream("users.txt");
```

or

```
ofstream user;
user.open("user.txt");
...
user.close("user.txt");
user("users.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

'ofstream' is used to write in a text or binary file. While 'new' is used to allocate memory. 
To write in the end of a file you need to first open it in 'append'(app) mode.It will automatically use the memory in your storage drive once its get connected to a file.

```
**user.seekp(0,std::ios::end);**
```

This line of code is not wrong but not required.

Replace this

```
ofstream user = new ofstream();
user("users.txt");
if (user.is_open()) {
    //Make sure the program is writing to the end of the file!
    user.seekp(0,std::ios::end);

    user << username << endl;
    user << password << endl;
    user << bio << endl;
}
```

by this:-

```
ofstream user("user.txt",ios::app);
if(user)
{
    user << username << endl;
    user << password << endl;
    user << bio << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the filename to the `ofstream` constructor.  Also, specify that you want to append to the file - there is no need to seek manually.

```
ofstream user("users.txt", ofstream::app);
if (user)
{
    user << username << endl;
    user << password << endl;
    user << bio << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Something went wrong with opening the file!";
}
```